# From property name as string to List.Contains(x.Property)

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

I have this:

```
// selectedOptions Contains a list of string constants
var selectedOptions = new List<string>(...); 
Expression<Func<T, bool>> condition = null;
switch (propertyName)
{
    case "Property1":
        condition = x => selectedOptions.Contains(x.Property1);
        break;
    case "Property1":
        condition = x => selectedOptions.Contains(x.Property2);
        break;
    case "Property3":
        condition = x => selectedOptions.Contains(x.Property3);
        break;
}
```

The condition is to be used as a predicate for Where() in Linq to Entities.
The idea is for EF to generate SQL something along the lines of `where Property1 in (...)`.
I don't know if there is a better way to do this, but it works.

My problem is that I would like to eliminate the switch and have something along the lines of:

```
condition = x => selectedOptions.Contains(x.[propertyName]);
```

Is it possible?

Comment: You need to build an expression tree by hand using the `Expression` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible:

```
var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
var containsMethod = typeof(List<string>).GetMethod("Contains");
var property = Expression.Property(parameter, propertyName);
var body = Expression.Call(Expression.Constant(selectedOptions), containsMethod, property);
condition = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, parameter);
```

This builds the expression tree by hand.